# Assembly IDE Similar to IDA's Graph View

Tags: windows, ide, assembly

I am looking for a IDE with a similar interface to IDA Pro's Graph View. The procedures and loops are separated nicely and it's easier to understand the code flow. Syntax highlighting would be a bonus!

The IDE doesn't need to be able to assemble code.

[image: IDA Pro's Graph View]